# Execute a testing.xml file from some other java project

Tags: java, logic, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng.xml

I have a swing jTable where in I have a column where all the at the test methods are listed and another column having the class names where the @test methods reside.
Is there any way that I can call the test methods of the particular classes from the Java swing project.